# GoogleMap mover câmera do mapa para determinada localização

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Adicionei o mapa no fragment, ele já está aparecendo, até adicionei um marcador aleatório com o mapa inicializando nele. o problema é que agora eu estou usando o GeoCoder.

Coloco o endereço no edittext e ele converte em Lng e Lat, ate ai tudo bem, ele ta convertendo e salvando no banco.

O que eu quero agora é que ao digitar o nome London (por exemplo) e apertar no botão ACHAR, ele mude a camera do mapa para a lat e lng de london.

O erro que está dando é de `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
MapsActivity mapa = new MapsActivity();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragLayout, mapa).commit();
```

GeoCoder

```
String stringLocal = localizacao.getText().toString();
    //Convertendo endereço para coordenada

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(stringLocal, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    double longitude = address.getLongitude();
    double latitude = address.getLatitude();
```

Codigo do botao achar.

```
 if (view == ACHAR) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
```

MapsFragment

```
public class MapsFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflate, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super .onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Comment: Verifique se as variáveis `latitude` e `longitude`, usadas no código do botão ACHAR, são as mesmas que são inicializadas no GeoCoder.